# how to integrate in msbuild in to solution

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, build-automation

I am working with integrating in MSBuild xml tasks file in to a visual studio 2012 solution. The file performs 2 tasks, 1 to validate against StyleCop, the other to run FxCop analysis. I have created the msbuild file from tutorials on the web.

My question is, where should the file be stored on the file system? I presume its outside of the solution. How do I set up the solution to run this msbuid file? I use TFS for source control and TFS Build 2010 for CI so I am looking to integrate it in to this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way that I have our source control tree laid out where I work:

```
Root
 -- Artifacts  (Reports folder for build.  Items are not checked into TFS)
 -- BuildOutput (location where all compiled code is sent.  Items are not checked into TFS)
 -- BuildScripts
   -- ConfigFiles (config files used for different kinds of builds)
   -- MSBuild (MSBuild scripts that I have written for our build)
   -- MSBuild Extensions (MSBuild extension that I use as part of my build)
 -- Database (folder for all database related items)
 -- src (folder for all DotNET source code)
 -- ThirdParty (folder to hold all of our third party dependencies like NUnit, Specflow, etc)
```

This has worked out fairly well for us.

Typically, when you want to integrate things like styleCop and FXCop you will include them as steps in your overall build process and not directly into a project or solution.  For example, the build process that I manage has 12 different steps that it performs.  I do things like 1) compile code, 2) run unit test and code coverage, 3) run integration tests, 4) run duplicate finder, etc.  You would want to set up the same kind of thing as part of your build process.

I do not have much experience with TFS Build (I started using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) by JetBrains over TFS Build) but you should be able to modify your build template to integrate your MSBuild scripts into your build process.  I also think there are some extensions for TFS Build that allow your to execute StyleCop and FXCop directly within the build template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is super information and really helps me. One thing I am unclear on, is the same build script executed when building the solution from within visual studio as building from your continous integration? This bit I am not clear on and what is best practise.

Comment: When selecting build within visual studio (pressing F6), no, that will just execute the build instructions for each of the project files.  The kinds of builds that I am talking about are actually executed on a server and not run locally.  If you want to execute your build configured TFS Build but do not want to commit your changes to TFS, you can use what is called a private build.  This is a pretty good article over private builds. http://www.sujitksingh.com/?p=64  In a nutshell it lets you run a build on the server without checking your changes into the branch you are working in.

Comment: Thanks again. The reason I want to include such as part of a developer building the solution is so that any build errors are caught at this point eg. Stylecop rules failing. Based on your information, I believe this is not possible. Unless I run the msbuild build automation as a build event from a .net project. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I do not recommend directly modifying .net project file though because if you decide to change your build process, you end up touching all of your project files as opposed to making a change to your build configuration. You can do other things like setting up a batch file that executes MSBuild to compile your solution and then run your other build item. However, this still would have to happen outside of VS.

Comment: What you are talking about is why Microsoft included the private build functionality though.  It allows the developer to test their changes against the build on the server before they check their code in.  This way they can make any changes that they need to correct things like Stylecop rule failures before committing their changes where other developers have access to them.